# How to display all numbers rather than just 1 number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.num_questions').each( function() {

$(this).val(qnum);
++qnum;
$(".questionNum").text(qnum);
```

});

I have a hidden input (`.num_questions`). Now lets say I have 2 questions, it displays qnum 1 and 2 but when I post it into the next page, it displays qnum '3' for both questions as that would of been the next question number.

So what I want to know is how can I get `$(".num_questions").val(qnum);` to not display the next question number when I post the hidden input, but to display all of the question numbers it has displayed, so if I have 2 questions, for each num_question it displays the qnum and then adds 1 to the qnum for the next question which should hopefully make qnum 1 for question 1 and qnum 2 for question 2 when I post the hidden input into the next page and not qnum '3' for both questions.

Below is the form:

```
    <form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="detailsBlock">
<table id="question">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        Question Number <span class="questionNum">1</span>
        <input type="hidden" class="num_questions" value="1" name="numQuestion">
    </th>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Now where you see the span .questionNum, this works fine because for every question it adds a question number and then adds 1 for the next question, hence you get question number 1 for first question, question number 2 for second question etc. But the problem is that I can't post a span tag. So I need a hidden input field to be able to post onto the next page. But the hidden input value is only displaying 1 number for all the questions and that would be the very next question number which is '3' for the 2 questions example. I need it to store all of the question numbers so that when I post it, it will show question number 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. 1 question number per question. It works fine with the span but it is not doing it for the hidden input field

Comment: Inside your .each() use this instead. `$(this).val(qnum);
`

Comment: should `qnum` have the same value for every item in the `each` loop?

Comment: @Mathletics No, for each item it should have a different value for qnum. For item 1 (question 1) the value should be '1', for item '2' (question 2) the value should be '2' and etc. But I have mutliple exams created so after first exam is complete, when I go to second exam, the value of qnum automatically goes back to '1', so I can't do a simple count hence why I need to display the qnum value

Answer (score 2):

By using `$(this)` inside your loop, you are referring to the particular element which is currently focused on during the loop, not just `$('.num_questions')` in general:

```
$('.num_questions').each(function() {
    $(this).val(qnum);
    ++qnum;
});​
```

Comment: I have changed the code above to match what you have said but it is still doing the same thing. If I add 1 question, instead of display '1' for question number, it is displaying '2' because that would be the next question number and as that number appears on the page, it takes that value

Comment: @user1304948 Edited answer to include your increment

Comment: It is still doing same thing. I wll update my code and include bit more info if it will help you